# How can I add username and password at runtime for Tomcate Datasource with Oracle UCP

Tags: java, tomcat8, ojdbc, ucp

I was trying to create a Datasource in tomcat with Oracle UCP and my requirement was not add the password at server.xml , I need to add that at server runtime, I have tried in many ways but didn't work.

Here is my code samples

server.xml in tomcat

```
<Resource 
       name="testds"
       connectionPoolName="testds"
       auth="Container"
       factory="com.test.tomcat.datasorceEncrypt.CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource"
       type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource"
       connectionFactoryClassName="com.test.tomcat.datasorceEncrypt.CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource2"
       jmxEnabled="true"
       initialPoolSize="10"
       minPoolSize="10"
       maxPoolSize="300"
       fastConnectionFailoverEnabled="true"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
            (HOST=localhost)(PORT=3203))(CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVICE_NAME=employee)))"
       sqlForValidateConnection="select 1 from DUAL" />
```

CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource .java

```
package com.test.tomcat.datasorceEncrypt;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl;

public class CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource extends PoolDataSourceImpl {

  /*    public CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource() {
        Properties dbProperties = null;

        try {

            this.setPassword("pass");
            this.setUser("user");
            System.out.println(this.getUser() + "-------" + this.getPassword());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {


        try {
            this.setPassword("pass");
            this.setUser("user");
            System.out.println(this.getUser() + "-------" + this.getPassword());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return super.getConnection(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getConnection(username, password);
    }



    @Override
    protected void createPoolWithDefaultProperties() throws SQLException {

        try {
            this.setPassword("pass");
            this.setUser("user");
            System.out.println(this.getUser() + "-------" + this.getPassword());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        super.createPoolWithDefaultProperties();
    }


}
```

CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource2.java

```
package com.test.tomcat.datasorceEncrypt;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource2 extends OracleDataSource {

    public CustomizeOracleUCPDataSource2() throws SQLException {
        super();
        this.setPassword("pass");
            this.setUser("user");
    }



    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        this.setPassword("pass");
            this.setUser("user");
        return super.getConnection(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        return super.getConnection(username, password);
    }



}
```

Nothing is working out my user name and passwords were printed in console, but couldn't able to set to the datasource.

I am getting below log info while datasource was getting created.

```
19-Dec-2019 19:34:35.763 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] oracle.ucp.logging.ClioSupport._log oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl:createPoolWithDefaultProperties:oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl@6b938ce5:Connection pool instance is 
19-Dec-2019 19:34:35.803 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] oracle.ucp.logging.ClioSupport._log oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl:createPool:oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl@6b938ce5:Connection pool instance is created
```

With the details aI am not able to create a datasource I am getting below Error :

```
 Error occurred while establishing connection to the Test database
```

Any help could be greatly appreciated.

I am using Ojdbc8.jar,ucp.jar

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieved encryption and decryption of  password in tomcat , this solution will work for all your password problems please go to this link for more details.

[Tomcat support for password encryption and deryption](https://tcserver.docs.pivotal.io/4x/docs-tcserver/topics/encoding-properties.html)